# swift how to use getelementsbytagname to return a value

Tags: cocoa, swift3, applescript, wkwebview, getelementsbytagname

I am a novice Swift 3.x programmer and I am trying to convert an AppleScript program to Swift that scrapes data from a website using WebKit in Cocoa (iMac desktop). The function VCgetInputByTag looks for html tag (theTag) and is suppose to return the text for that tag. When I try to use this function, the print("text= (response)") displays the data I want but I can't get the function VCgetInputByTag to return that string.  Please advise.

func VCgetInputByTag(theTag : String, num : Int) -> String {

```
  var webTagText : String

  webTagText = ""


  webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByTagName('\(theTag)')[\(num)].innerHTML;") {(response:Any?, error:Error?) in
     if (response != nil) {
        webTagText = response as! String
        webTagText = "\(response)"
        print("text= \(response)")
     }
     // error handling
  }



  print(webTagText)
  return webTagText
```

}

The AppleScript version that I use and works is

to getInputByTag(theTag, num) -- defines a function with two inputs, theTag and num

```
tell application "Safari" --tells AS that we are going to use Safari

    set input to do JavaScript "document.getElementsByTagName('" & theTag & "')[" & num & "].innerHTML;" in document 1

end tell

return input
```

end getInputByTag

Thanks to all in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The `evaluateJavaScript` function is asynchronous, so you cannot return the resulting string from `VCgetInputByTag` function synchronously. What you need is a completion handler to return the result asynchronously.

```
func VCgetInputByTag(theTag : String, num : Int, completionHandler:@escaping (_ result:String)->Void){

    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByTagName('\(theTag)')[\(num)].innerHTML;") {(response:Any?, error:Error?) in
      if let result = response as? String{
         print("text= \(response)")
         completionHandler(result)
      }
       // error handling
    }
}
```

Comment: var webTagText : String  
        
      webTagText = ""  

VCgetInputByTag(theTag : theTag, num : num ) {  
         (result: String) in<br/>
         print("outside= \(result)")<br/>
         webTagText = result<br/>
         print("webTag Texta= \(webTagText)")<br/>
      }<br/>
<br/>
//Once VCgetInputByTag runs and result has data, it never executes the lines below:<br/>
      print("webTagText=\(webTagText)")<br/>
      return webTagText<br/>

Comment: Its the same concept. `VCgetInputByTag` is also asynchronous. You cannot use `return` statements with asynchronous functions. `webTagText` is assigned asynchronously at a later time than when you are trying to print and return it - at which point it is still an empty string. You said "Once VCgetInputByTag runs and result has data, it never executes the lines below" - wrong, it executes the lines below "before" it has the result.

Comment: So how can I execute the code "after" it has the result?

Comment: Just put the code you want to execute inside the completion handler - after you know you have the result.